# What is the correct place to register class maps for mongodb in asp.net core?

Tags: .net, mongodb, asp.net-core

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();

            ClassMapper.RegisterMappings();
        }
    }
```

I have created ClassMapper class to handle all mappings. I am calling registermappings in program Main method. Is this right way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConfigureServices` in `Startup` (Startup.cs).

If you do it like in your example, they won't be executed, when you run integration tests with [TestServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing), because there you can only use the `Startup` as generic type parameter of `testServer.UseStartup<T>()`.

`Configure` method of `Startup` may already be too late, depending on how and what you instantiate.